# Best way to compare two arrays with JSON objects as items in python

Tags: python, arrays, json, python-3.x

You have two arrays (dummy values) with JSON objects as each item inside the arrays:

ArrayOne:

`[{'keyboards': '1'}, {'keyboards': '2'}, {'keyboards': '3'}, {'mice': '1'}]`

ArrayTwo:

`[{'keyboards': '1'}, {'keyboards': '2'}, {'mice': '1'}]`

I want to loop through each array simultaneously and IF a value in arrayOne exists in arrayTwo but doesnt in arrayTwo, then flag it up (do something).

This is my code example:

```
for deviceAndID in ArrayOne:
        if deviceAndID in ArrayTwo:
             print("It exists in both arrays")
        else:
             print("Device " + str(deviceAndID) + "is not in arrayTwo")
```

With this code example it prints out (an example) `Device {'keyboard': '1'} is not in arrayTwo` for every value in the largest array.

Really I need it to print out the following based on the two arrays above:

```
It exists in both arrays
It exists in both arrays
Device {'keyboard': '3'} is not in arrayTwo
It exists in both arrays
```

I have a feeling the issue is caused by the fact each element or item is a json object, so how would I go about this considering they're JSON objects inside the list?

Comment: What's the problem you are facing? I ran your code and the result was the code you included at the bottom of your question.

Comment: @AmirAfianian really?? not for me it doesn't and I just copied and pasted?

Comment: Yes, I'm gonna post what I've run along with the results

Comment: @AmirAfianian thanks, add it to the bottom of my question maybe? That's really odd?

Comment: @Nathan, I tested it too, works exactly as in your output

Comment: @Kamil I'm doing it on my machine and the output it just `Device {'keyboard': '1'} is not in arrayTwo` for every line??

Comment: Can you put `print(type(deviceAndID))` after `for deviceAndID in ArrayOne:`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is what I got based on your question:

```
>>> ArrayOne = [{'keyboards': '1'}, {'keyboards': '2'}, {'keyboards': '3'}, {'mice': '1'}]
>>> ArrayTwo = [{'keyboards': '1'}, {'keyboards': '2'}, {'mice': '1'}]
>>> for deviceAndID in ArrayOne:
        if deviceAndID in ArrayTwo:
             print("It exists in both arrays")
        else:
             print("Device " + str(deviceAndID) + "is not in arrayTwo")

             
It exists in both arrays
It exists in both arrays
Device {'keyboards': '3'}is not in arrayTwo
It exists in both arrays
```